# Azure DevOps Manage IIS task deploy fails due to insufficent permissions yet account is in local admin group

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After a successful build using a hosted VS2017 agent, I'm trying to deploy on-prem using an local hosted agent which was setup using a domain account which should have sufficient permissions as it is in the local admin group.  As I was digging around on this issue elsewhere, one user re-installed their agent using `NTATHORITY\SYSTEM` and it worked.

I d'ont really need to create or stop\start the website, just deploy the recent build artifact.
What permissions should I check or should I use another task?

[image]

> 019-04-06T21:03:10.3898646Z ERROR ( message:Configuration error 
>   2019-04-06T21:03:10.3899503Z
>
> 2019-04-06T21:03:10.3899791Z Filename: redirection.config
>   2019-04-06T21:03:10.3900026Z  2019-04-06T21:03:10.3900293Z Line
>   Number: 0 2019-04-06T21:03:10.3900530Z  2019-04-06T21:03:10.3900852Z
>   Description: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient
>   permissions 2019-04-06T21:03:10.3901076Z  2019-04-06T21:03:10.3901333Z
>   . ) 2019-04-06T21:03:10.8135484Z ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited
>   with code '5'.

Answer (score 11):

An agent is running under a user. The error means that your user doesn't have permissions to read/modify the `redirection.config` file that is necessary to manage IIS.

You have multiple options to solve this.

1. Change the user were the agent is running under. In example: `NTATHORITY\SYSTEM`
2. Give permissions to the user were your agent is running under to the folder `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`. If you want to create app pools or websites etc, modify permissions are of course needed.

Comment: While granting NETWORK SERVICE permission to the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config did fix this one error, it still wasn't enough to have permissions to start/stop sites.  I ended up using the advice in the other answer to run the Agent as "Local System".

Answer (score 10):

When we install Azure agent as a service(In Windows, search for 'Services' and look for something like Azure Pipelines Agent..), by default it is logged on as 'Network Service'. Change it to 'Local System' and the pipeline should be able to run IIS related tasks/commands.